# Can't Insert value in Django foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have tried to insert Value in Foreign key fields in django. But It show's me error like this:-
**Cannot assign "'95'": "Catalog.author_id" must be a "Author" instance.**
But when I tried to insert with django shell It doesn't show me any error, It's Works fine. Please Help Me
I have attached my codes that You can understand well

**Models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.author_id)


class Catalog(models.Model):
    book_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year_of_publish = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    author_id = models.ForeignKey('Author', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book_id)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class Catalog_Details(forms.ModelForm):
book_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control',
           'placeholder': 'Enter book id'}
), required=True, max_length=50)

title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control',
           'placeholder': 'Enter title'}
), required=True, max_length=50)
year_of_publish = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control',
           'placeholder': 'Enter Published Year'}
), required=True, max_length=5)
author_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Author.objects.values_list(
    'author_id', flat=True))

price = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-control',
           'placeholder': 'Enter Price'}
), required=True, max_length=50)

class Meta():
    model = Catalog
    fields = ['book_id', 'title', 'year_of_publish', 'price', 'author_id']
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def catalog(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = Catalog_Details(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                author_id = form.cleaned_data['author_id']
                m = Author.objects.get(author_id=author_id)
                c1 = Catalog(book_id=form.cleaned_data['book_id'], title=form.cleaned_data['title'],
                           year_of_publish=form.cleaned_data['year_of_publish'],price=form.cleaned_data['price'], author_id=m)
                c1.save()
                form = Catalog_Details()

        else:
            form = Catalog_Details()
        return render(request, 'catalog.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: The queryset for the `author_id` field should probably just be `Author.objects.all()`

Comment: @IainShelvington I think that shouldn't be a problem, because OP is retrieving `Author` object in view. So `m` should be an `Author` object.

Comment: @sandip the error is from `c1 = Catalog(book_id=form.cleaned...` statement, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is even necessary to override `author_id` field in Forms. You can remove `author_id` from `Catalog_Details`. And you can update your view like this:

```
@login_required
def catalog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Catalog_Details(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = Catalog_Details()
            # here you should redirect to a success page to know `Catalog_Details` has been created
    else:
        form = Catalog_Details()
    return render(request, 'catalog.html', {'form': form})
```

**FYI**, you should not name `ForeignKey` Fields with suffix `_id`, because django creates that for you. For example: in your case, you will find a field `author_id_id` in `Catalog` model which will return an integer value(primary key of Author table's column).